# Detect document marker on document

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, document, marker

I want to detect a certain marker on a document.

The marker would be "666⑁" (three sixes and the [OCR-Chair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCR-A#Dedicated_OCR-A_characters_in_Unicode); The font is [OCR-A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCR-A)) and the document would be a [german prescription](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Kassenrezept_Muster_2008.svg). I have about a few hundred-thousand documents. The documents might be rotated or even skewed and sometimes there are two prescriptions on one document.

I would not call myself a Data Scientist, but I am familiar with Python (OpenCV, Pandas).

**What would be the best way to approach? Can you recommend steps to approach my problem?**

I already looked into Sift but it seems to be good only for photos.

Regards.

Comment: May I ask you if and how you solve it? I'm working on a similar problem

Comment: I tried this tutorial: https://pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/26/multi-scale-template-matching-using-python-opencv/
If you have a better approach, please contact me. We would offer to pay for a working solutions.

Comment: @devilteo911 We've used SIFT to detect the whole form that contained the marker.